# Laptop hardware damaged?

Tags: hardware-failure

Windows 7 x64 blue screened every few minutes with error code 124, but worked in secure mode.(EDIT: safe mode) I tried reinstalling windows, which didn't work, so i tried to install various Linux systems which also didn't work. the computer freezes most times on installing or gives a detailed erro rmsg like this one (its always the same with CPU bank stuff):

[image: https://i.imgur.com/N4iUA8r.jpg]

Super detailed system specs: https://www.dropbox.com/s/90avdgo61o0j57y/hardinfo_report.html?dl=0

The only thing that works is a 2013 version of parted magic, a "repair" linux distro. so we could do all sorts of checks!

btw, disabling cpu cores is not possible in bios.

is this just a simple "cpu is damaged" problem? i found the same cpu for 10€ on ebay

EDit:

@secure mode

its actually called safe mode (sry english is not my first language)

@resetting your BIOS settings to defaults?

yes, i tried that, and enabling disabling different features in bios

@other routine checks like running a memory checking tool

i did alot of test from this disc: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ i did different memory checks, cpu tests and hdd checks. nothing interesting came out.

@cpufan

idk how to check this as it is a laptop. i can hear a fan and it dosnt crash or burn during "system stability tester" from parted magic. (wich is a program to stresstest cpu by calculating millions of digits of pi) sensors temperature is at 60°C during this stresstest, (65°C max only hit shortly) so i guess its working

@mobo

ill open it up and edit the post (the mainboard has been swapped by lenovo service)